# Compare values Jquery and sum

Tags: jquery

i have a table, the second column have the country, i have many countries, but i need show how many are from US, and how many are from japan.

i use this code to have the values from the column, but
how i compare and count this values?

```
var items=[];
//Iterate all td's in second column
$('#MyTable>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2)').each( function(){
   //add item to array
   items.push( $(this).text() );       
});
```

and i need display this into the bottom of the table

here is the HTML

```
<table id="MyTable" width="620px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td class="country">US</td>
            <td><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a></td>
            <td>12/21/2012</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td> </td>
            <td class="country">Japan</td>
            <td><a href="http://google.info" target="_blank">google.info</a></td>
            <td>12/21/2012</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td class="country">Japan</td>
            <td><a href="http://google.info" target="_blank">google.info</a></td>
            <td>12/21/2012</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td>Migration</td>
            <td class="country">tokyo</td>
            <td><a href="http://google.info" target="_blank">google.info</a></td>
            <td>12/21/2012</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

should display Japan 2, US: 1 Tokyo: 1

Comment: At the absolute minimum, we need samples of what's in `$(this).text()`, but it'd be best to provide a few rows of your table  markup that represent your data set.

Comment: Not sure I got this: `how many are from US, and how many are from japan`. You're talking about countries, aren't you?

Comment: @MelanciaUK -- I'm guessing that should be cities

Comment: @tymeJV yes, it makes more sense.

Comment: Tokyo ain't a country

Comment: Since you already have an array of strings from the code you've posted, you can just loop through that array and compare the array values to the string values you're looking for, and add to a counter for each one when you find a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, you can have a look at this fiddle: it does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/QtBlueWaffle/LHK8h/2/

But you should have a look at : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

Here is the code I used:

```
var items = [];
//Iterate all td's in second column
$('#MyTable>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2)').each(function () {
    //add item to array
    items.push($(this).text());
});

var countries = [];
var countriesNumbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i = i + 1) {
    var index = countries.indexOf(items[i]);
    if (index != -1) {
        countriesNumbers[index] += 1;
    } else {
        countries.push(items[i]);
        countriesNumbers.push(1);
    }

}

// Build the resulting string
var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i += 1) {
    result = result.concat(countries[i]).concat(":").concat(countriesNumbers[i]).concat(";");
}
// Show the result
$("#result").html(result);
```

Hope this helps